# Running karate tests in TFS Build (.net and python project )

Tags: python, .net, tfs, bdd, karate

I am a java developer and I use karate to test a Rest API (python project) and (.net project), how can I run my test in tfs build in the 2 projects ?

I use the standalone jar to execute my features.

Comment: Refer to the "Standalone Execution" section of this tutorial: https://automationpanda.com/2018/12/10/testing-web-services-with-karate/

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK TFS provides a way to run maven projects. If you API server is deployed on some machine like a *QA Env* then, Use TFS and run maven job which runs your karate tests against the environment

you can also follow this thread. which provides a containerized solution, using docker images.

https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/396